# UML Class Diagram - Do we include partial classes like usercontrols and MainWindow here?

Tags: c#, class, uml, diagram

I am working on a project and I am not very sure about how to do this. I have all my classes in my UML diagram, but I am not sure if I have to include partial classes like usercontrols here. 
My code is in C# if that matter.

I think I don't have to do it but I want to see others opinion on the matter.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

UML is neutral about what you should include as class in your model.  So it's your choice.  And the choice will depend on your development method and what you want to achieve.

For example, the [Unified Software Development Process](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unified_Process),  defined by the fathers of UML, Booch, Jacobson & Rumbaugh, propose different levels of modelling:

- Analysis classes are derived from use-cases and follow the [Entity-Control-Boundary approach](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity-control-boundary)
- Design classes are derived from analysis model and correspond to the classes to be implemented.

Other methods, such as [AgileUP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Agile_Unified_Process), are more pragmatic, and start with a [domain model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain_model) focused on persistent classes corresponding to the business concepts.  The design model enriches the domain classes with other classes invovled in the implementation (e.g. UI, application controls, persistence utilities, etc.)

Moreover, there is a difference between the classes in a model, and the subset of classes that you show in a diagram for discussing a particular aspect of your design.

Additional context (i.e. purpose of your UML model and metodology) is needed for more specific advice.

Comment: Thank you. It's a final project for College, hence my limited knowledge on this. I have made UML class diagrams, but I never had to choose what to include or not. My usercontrols are windows that will appear in order to show a form to add a player into a database, search a player from a database, and so on. So they mostly use the classes in order to do so.
 I was thinking I could do two Diagrams: one with only classes and another one showing the relationships between them and the usercontrols?

I just don't' want to do something that is going to be a mess without any sense.

Thanks again.

Comment: @CarlosMira Indeed, the approach with several diagrams seems a very promising one.  In your report you can introduce each diagram with a textual description corresponding for the specific aspect that you document with your diagram. For example Diagram 1 could be a domain model of the content of your database (e.g. player, game,  and association between these classes).  Diagram 2 could be the UI design showing usercontrols and their associations.   Alternatively, DIagram 2 could be a zoom on a couple fo dimain objects together with their user controls as well as persistence classes.

Comment: Thanks again. I really like that better, the idea of having two Class Diagrams. I was so focused on what to include, that I never thought about doing two of them until I saw your first answer. I will mark it as answered.